# Python standard error plotting of a distribution

Tags: python, plot

If we are given mean and standard deviation of a distribution.
How do you plot standard error bars on python? Could find anywhere about this.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

`matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar` will do what you need. See here:

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [1, 3, 2, 4, 3]
sd = [0.5, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.25]

plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=sd, capsize=2)

plt.show()
```

[image: matplotliberrorbarexample]

In case you mean that you want to plot error on a histogram, you can do so with `hist` and `errorbar`, using the values for occurences and bins that `hist` returns:

```py
import numpy as np

dist = [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]
n, bins = plt.hist(dist, bins=np.unique(dist))[0:2]
binX = 0.5 * (bins[1:] + bins[:-1])
plt.errorbar(binX, n, yerr=sd, fmt='none', capsize=2)

plt.show()
```

[image: matplotlibhisterrorexample]